# Unable to connect Windows 10 PC to Raspberry Pi Samba share

Tags: networking, windows, samba

I'm following this [tutorial](https://tektab.com/2015/11/07/setting-up-file-sharingnas-using-samba-on-raspberry-pi/) to set up RPi file sharing/NAS via Samba.

As per the *Client access to NAS* instructions I typed my Pi's IP address into the “search program and files box” from the windows command prompt (i.e. **\\192.168.1.113\public**), and typed in my username and password as per the instructions.

The folder **RASPBERRYPI\public** now appears in the Win 10 **Network** folder, but when I double-click the folder the following error message appears:

> \\RASPBERRYPI\public is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
>
> The user name could not be found.

I am unsure why I am unable to connect to my Pi, as the SMB server appears to be running properly from the Pi's end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain it is because the permissions / owner on the drives when you mounted them (if you are using external drives) was not set correctly. See the tutorial I am linking. http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/

Comment: This worked so thanks for the quick and helpful reply! I still have a **\\public** folder in my Network shares though, and it appears that on the Pi my USB drive has been mounted twice in /media (16GB and USBHDD1 respectively). Is there a way to clean these up so only the working folders/mounted drives appear?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on your problem but I'd try to sudp rm -r /media/16GB as long as it isn't mounted.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin

sudo mkdir /home/pi/yourfolder

sudo chmod -R 777 /home/pi/yourfolder

sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

## On end of file

```
[yourfolder]
  comment = shared without password
  path = /home/pi/yourfolder
  browseable = yes
  writeable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
```

sudo service smbd restart

-- Test your new folder.

Comment: Creating a world readable/writeable share is not only a security issue but likely unnecessary.

Comment: Very beautiful phrase (I will use). Could you help us solve the problem?

Comment: sudo mkdir /home/pi/yourfolder
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/pi/yourfolder
--- supress this commands

and add user pi and make one passw to samba.
 sudo smbpasswd -a pi